# Starting a WP8 game

Tags: windows-phone-8

Back when WP 7.5 was the latest Windows Phone OS, I could create games using the XNA framework. I knew that I could use C# for that.

But now I see, that the WP8 SDK doesn't support XNA and I know that it's deprecated now. 
So my question is:

**How can I write a game for Windows Phone 8 using C#?**

Answer (score 0):

There are open source projects such as SharpDX that are trying to port XNA/DirectX functionality to C#.  However, its reccomended you use C++ and Direct3D to create a Windows Phone 8 game.  Using C++ will net you higher performance than C# (at least it should) and you'll have access to all windows phone 8 features.  If you decide to go this route check out the DirectX toolkit project from Microsoft as it include C++ methods that simulate XNA behavior such as spritebatch.  On a final note I believe the Unity3D engine is going to support windows phone soon and that uses C# or JavaScript for all the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot develop XNA apps for the #WP8 platform directly. You can only target the WP7 platform with your XNA apps and they will run on WP8 devices just fine.

XNA projects in VS2012 and the WP8 SDK can only target the WP 7.1 platform. On the upside, all phones running WP 7.5, the upcoming 7.8 and WP8 will run your game without any issues. From that point of view, XNA is fully supported in the WP8 SDK, on WP8 devices, but these WILL NOT be WP8 projects.

By not being WP8 projects, the downside is that you CANNOT use WP8-exclusive features, such as:

1. In-app purchasing / micro-transactions (this one hurts XNA devs the most)
2. Your games will always be 800x480 since you need WP8 projects to support higher resolutions. Your XNA games should automatically scale up when run on devices with a higher resolution.
3. Exclusive WP8 networking features & APIs, including Bluetooth and NFC
4. Speech and voice recognition APIs
5. Your XNA game cannot register a protocol extension for app-to-app communications
6. New Live Tile templates

Final option obviously being what @Strife has said in his answer correctly.
Cheers.